# Contour integral $\oint_C \frac{p^2(z)}{|p(z)|^2} \frac{dz}{iz}$ over the unit circle $C$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm trying to find the contour integral over the unit circle $C$:

$$\oint_C \frac{p^2(z)}{|p(z)|^2} \frac{dz}{iz}$$
where

$$p(z) = a - z \sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_n z^n \\a, c_n, z \in \mathbb{C}$$

Specifically $c_n$ are the coefficients from a Fourier transform of some real sample points.  As such $c_n = \overline{c}_{-n}$.

I'm guessing the integral can be expressed in terms of the roots of $p(z)$, but I'm not sure of the best way to proceed.

### Edit

Working on it more, I've made what I think is partial progres:

Letting $r(z) = \sum_{n=-N}^N c_n z^n$, noting that $\overline{r(z)} = r(z)$, and with some polynomial long division:

$$\oint_C \frac{p^2(z)}{|p(z)|^2} \frac{dz}{iz} = \oint_C \frac{p(z)}{\overline{p(z)}} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\= \oint_C \frac{a - z \cdot r(z)}{\overline{a} - \frac{1}{z} r(z)} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\= \oint_C (z^2 + \frac{\overline{a}z^3 - az}{r(z) - \overline{a} z}) \frac{dz}{iz}
\\= -i \oint_C (z + \frac{\overline{a}z^2 - a}{r(z) - \overline{a} z}) dz
\\= -i \oint_C \frac{\overline{a}z^2 - a}{r(z) - \overline{a} z} dz
$$

But what to do now?  I was thinking I could find the roots of $r(z) - \overline{a}z$ and find the residues at these roots, but I'm not sure if that has a nice format?  There'd be lots of repeated factors in the denominator of each residue, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Since $z$ is on the unit circle, $\bar z =1/z$. Thus
\begin{align*}
& \frac{{p^2 (z)}}{{\left| {p(z)} \right|^2 }}\frac{1}{{iz}} = \frac{{p(z)}}{{\overline {p(z)} }}\frac{1}{{iz}} = \frac{{a - z\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_n z^n } }}{{\bar a - \bar z\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_{ - n} \bar z^n } }}\frac{1}{{iz}} = \frac{{a - z\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_n z^n } }}{{\bar a - \dfrac{1}{z}\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_{ - n} z^{ - n} } }}\frac{1}{{iz}} \\ & = \frac{{a - z\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_n z^n } }}{{\bar a - \dfrac{1}{z}\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_n z^n } }}\frac{1}{{iz}} = \frac{{a - z\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_n z^n } }}{{\bar a - \dfrac{1}{z}\sum\limits_{n =  - N}^N {c_n z^n } }}\frac{1}{{iz}} = \frac{1}{i}\frac{{zp(z)}}{{\bar az^2  - a + p(z)}}.
\end{align*}
Therefore the integral is
$$
2\pi \sum {{\mathop{\rm Res}\nolimits} \frac{{zp(z)}}{{\bar az^2  - a + p(z)}}} .
$$
The sum is over the residues inside the unit circle.

Comment: I think this is a good start but it's not obvious to me that $\overline{a}z^2 - a + p(z)$ is easier to find roots for (so you can find the singularties at which to evaluate the residues) than just $\overline{p(z)}$ before all the algebra.

Comment: I just wanted to get an analytic expression under the integral. That is a prerequisite of the residue theorem. In general, the conjugate of an analytic function is not analytic.